# Yii - Multiple CGridView in One Page for Relations

Tags: php, yii

I have the following relation scheme:

`1 portfolio -> Many Users in each Portfolio -> Each User owns many Products`

Entities: Portfolio, User, Products

What I would like to display is in one page:
1. The name of the portfolio
2. The title of a user
3. CGridView of all products owned by that user

It seems, if CGridView were not being used, you would populate your model appropriately and then use a foreach loop to loop through each user relation and then loop through the products related to that user. And create a render_partial view for the products and for the user.

However, I am at a complete loss as how to accomplish this with CGridView.

Any advice is much, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to render the User's Products in a CGridView?

To render data with a CGridView you need to pass in a CDataProvider to populate the view. So the question is: how do you make a CDataProvider for the HAS_MANY relation?

Surprisingly, the `CActiveDataProvider` does not support relations in this way. What you need to do get the relation and pass that data into a `CArrayDataProvider`. Assuming the `$user->products`relation,you can do it like this:

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($user->products, array());
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'columns'=>array(
    'id', // your columns here
  ),
));
```

It's not ideal, but it works. Credit goes here for this specific technique: http://learnyii.blogspot.com/2010/12/yii-how-to-display-related-hasmany-grid.html

Comment: "$rawData=$user->products, $config=array()" This is funny. You should not call method like that.

Comment: Huh, yeah that is weird, I'm not sure where that is coming from. Looking at the link I credited it might have come over from there as some gratuitous copypasta. I fixed it, thanks.